# Mass variable declaration and assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

Trying to create a batch of dictionaries:

```
January = {}
February = {}
March = {}
```

I would rather do something like:
January, February, March... = {}

which of course doesn't work.

Ultimately, I'm wanting to create a dictionary of these dictionaries:

```
MONTHS_DICT = {'01':January,'02':February...}
```

Its not a ton of code to do it line by line but I'm just learning Python and.... doing something repetitive typically tells me it can be done more efficiently in some other way.

Thoughts?

p.s. I'm working with python 2.x but if using 3 for this example would be of some help, that's not a problem.

Comment: "doing something repetitive typically tells me it can be done more efficiently in some other way".  Correct.  But loading up a lot of dictionaries with pre-cooked keys is probably wrong, also.  Look at `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: Create classes, dude. You're trying to re-invent the wheel with primitive types there. Encapsulate the details, and work on a higher level. OOP 101

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic This was actually before I knew OOP 101 :) However, I've needed this type of behavior ('mass' variable assignment) in more situations, so the question probably still has some use on that ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to month names as variables if you don't use them? You could simply write

```
month_dicts = [{} for _ in range(12)] # twelve dicts
numbers = ["%02d" % x for x in range(1,13)] # strings "01" ... "12"

# the dict
MONTHS_DICT = dict(zip(numbers, month_dicts))
# the dict for March
MONTHS_DICT["03"]
```

Comment: Slightly more condensed: `dict((%2d" % i, {}) for i in range(1, 13))` (and in 2.7+ you can use a dictionary comprehension, saving a few parens).

Comment: Parsing a txt file with several thousand lines, each line set to  a particular month (in no order) as '01', '02', etc. Was planning on using the above method to parse the month out of the line, then doing MONTHS_DICT[line[3:5]] to select the proper month dictionary (january, february), at which point I'll add the data of interest to it.

Comment: lol...realized I just gave an answer to the wrong question.  At end of program I'm writing data to a new file; was planning on using the name of dict as the Row name. Ended up just getting curious as to how batch variables can be assigned.

Comment: @george: Yeah, that's why you don't need variables like `March = {}` - you can't turn a string like `"03"` into the variable `March`. With the dict I've given it is you can do what you want: `this_lines_month = MONTHS_DICT[line[3:5]]; this_lines_month['data_of_interest'] = line`. To turn the number of a month into it's name you just need another dictionary: `{'01' : 'January', etc ...}` - you can construct that dictionary in the same way as above.

Comment: Answers the question I asked and the one I didn't - kudos :)

Answer (score 9):

```
January, February, March = {}, {}, {}
```

That's a little bit more concise way to do the initial declaration.

Answer (score 3):

Careful!

You can do:

```
foo = bar = baz = ''
```

But you can NOT do:

```
foo = bar = baz = {}
```

without having all of `foo`, `bar` and `baz` point to the same variable due to reference!

```py
>>> foo = bar = baz = {}
>>> bar
{}
>>> foo
{}
>>> baz
{}
>>> foo['test'] = 1
>>> foo
{'test': 1}
>>> bar
{'test': 1}
>>> baz
{'test': 1}
```

The most concise way to assign empty dictionaries to multiple variables is probably:

```py
foo, bar, baz = {}, {}, {}
```